# When overriding `init` method, why it is important to define it again?

Tags: objective-c

I had an exercise to override init method, so I need to create an `init` method that will set some attributes as well.

My question is: why do I need to define the original `init` method as well? in case that the new `init` method won't work?

This is my `.h` file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "XYPoint.h"

@interface Rectangle: NSObject

@property float width, height, tx, ty;

-(XYPoint *) origin;
-(void) setOrigin: (XYPoint *) pt;
-(void) translate: (XYPoint *) point;
-(id) initWithWidth:(int) w andHeight:(int) h;
-(id) init;

@end
```

And `.m` (only the init methods):

```
-(id) initWithWidth:(int)w andHeight:(int)h
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
        [self setWidth:w andHeight:h];
    }

    return self;
}

-(id) init
{
    return [self initWithWidth:0 andHeight:0];
}
```

I know that it is good this way, but if someone can explain me why is that I would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea is to have a central point of initialization for your object instead of sprinkling the initialization of variables throughout each init method.

Your particular example doesn't do much justice to this pattern because you're initializing a Rectangle with 0 width and 0 height, and the default NSObject implementation resets the memory for all instance variables to zero by default, and your `initWithWidth:andHeight:` method does the same. However, suppose that, you were allocating unit rectangles (width 1, height 1) by default when a Rectangle object was created using,

```
[[Rectangle alloc] init]
```

then instead of doing this,

```
- (id)initWithWidth:(int)width andHeight:(int)height {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setWidth:width andHeight:height];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setWidth:1 andHeight:1];
    }
    return self.
}
```

you're centralizing the point of initialization by just doing,

```
- (id)initWithWidth:(int)width andHeight:(int)height {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setWidth:w andHeight:h];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)init {
    return [self initWithWidth:1 andHeight:1];
}
```

This also goes hand in hand with the principle of [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) a.k.a. Don't Repeat Yourself.

This is a trivial example, however, in most real-world objects, you might have a much more complicated setup with notification registration, KVO registration, etc., and then it becomes absolutely crucial that your centralize all that initialization logic.

Comment: thanks allot! and why is those methods needs to return `id` type? if I know what type will be calling them..? @Anurag

Comment: Keeping the return type `id` has the flexibility that it'll automatically be casted to the proper type when subclassing, and that happens at compile time, so you'll get warnings/errors if you try to call instance methods on the returned object that don't exist in the class on which `alloc` was called. Hope I'm not confusing things further. However, remember that this compiler checks luxury only exists for instance methods and not class methods.

Comment: Better to use instancetype because when you use 'id', you get essentially no type checking at all. With instancetype, the compiler and IDE know what type of thing is being returned, and can check your code better and autocomplete better.

Comment: The compiler already takes care of converting id to instancetype for methods beginning with alloc, init, and new methods, but it's better to be explicit. See [Adopting Modern Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ModernizationObjC/AdoptingModernObjective-C/AdoptingModernObjective-C.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014150-CH1-SW11)

Comment: From the above article, "In your code, replace occurrences of id as a return value with instancetype where appropriate. This is typically the case for init methods and class factory methods. Even though the compiler automatically converts methods that begin with “alloc,” “init,” or “new” and have a return type of id to return instancetype, it doesn’t convert other methods. Objective-C convention is to write instancetype explicitly for all methods."

Answer (score 2):

You don't have do. You generally have one initializer that calls super (self = [super initWithXX]) and the others defer to that one.

In your specific example above its a good idea because initWithWidth:andHeight is acting as the main initializer, so if you call the default what ever code that needs to run in the main initializer will get called.

Btw: Use of the word 'and' in your initializer parameters is a little archaic by modern Objective-C conventions.